# Given a list of integers, split it into 2 list that return True if it is equal, else, return False (If it is impossible)

Tags: python

Same as before, I am given a list of string, and I have to split that ONE list into two list to check if it is possible to have equal sum. If possible, return array 1 and array 2.

The following code works for ONE set of combination

Eg. myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

Each full iteration will do the following **(targetSum = sum(myArr) / 2)** #5

#1: PartialArr1 = [1] , PartialArr2 = [2,3,4] , Check if Arr1 == targetSum

#1: PartialArr1 = [1, 2] , PartialArr2 = [3,4] , Check if Arr1 == targetSum

#1: PartialArr1 = [1, 2, 3] , PartialArr2 = [4] , Check if Arr1 == targetSum

#1: PartialArr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4] , PartialArr2 = [] , Check if Arr1 == targetSum

While #1 does not returns any True value, permutate the number ONCE

#2: myArr = [2, 3, 4, 1]

#2: PartialArr1 = [2] , PartialArr2 = [3,4,1] , Check if Arr1 == targetSum

#2: PartialArr1 = [2, 3] , PartialArr2 = [4,1] , Check if Arr1 == targetSum #**Return PartialArr1, PartialArr2**

```
def group(s):

    sumOfArr = sum(s)
    isPossible = sumOfArr%2

    if(isPossible == 0):
        #No remainder, possible to get a combination of two equal arrays
        targetSum = int(sumOfArr/2)

        partialArr1 = []
        partialArr2 = []
        i = 0
    
        while(targetSum != sum(partialArr1)):
            partialArr1.append(s[i])
            partialArr2 = s[i+1:]
        
            i+=1
        
            if(i == len(s)-1) or (sum(partialArr1) > targetSum):
                partialArr1 = []
                partialArr2 = []
                i = 0
                s = s[1:] + s[:1]

        return partialArr1,partialArr2
    else:
        #Not possible, return None, None
        return None, None
```

While my solution works for most permutation group, it doesn't work on the following:

```
#The following works with my code ->
#s = [135, 129, 141, 121, 105, 109, 105, 147]
#s = [-14, 3, 4, 13, -1, -5, 0, 5, -10, 8, -4, 10, -12, 11, 9, 12, -6, -11, -9, -8]
#s= [-1, 1, 4, 2, 8, 0]
#s = [10, 2,2,10, 2, 2, 2,10]


#SOLUTION SHOULD RETURN THE FOLLOWING
#s1 = [6, 10, 6, 10], sum(s1) = 32
#s2 = [7, -3, 1, -4, 2, 2, 7, -3, 2, 4, 0, 7, 6, -2, -4, 10], sum(s1) = 32


s = [7, -3, 6, 1, 10, -4, 2, 2, 6, 7, -3, 2, 4, 0, 7, 6, -2, 10, -4, 10]

group(s) #This does not work because it does not permutate all possible ways of len(s)^2 ways. Thus I am stucked at this point of time
```

Any help will be appreciated!! Thanks!!

Comment: Your while loop is only testing one split of the array, whereas the question (and examples) shows that you need to test many (if not all) combinations. So the  solution would depend on the context (is this question part of a lecture on brute-force algos, using combinations? on dynamic programming? or is a greedy solution acceptable?)

Comment: Hi there's no requirement to what method i'm using, however I have edited my answer, please take a look, right now i'm stuck by doing multiple permutations of [1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,1], [3,4,1,2], [4,3,2,1] << This will be one set of permutation while I should have another set [2,1,3,4] and so on.. but i am out of ideas of how to do this portion

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you need to see if your array can be divided into 2 equal arrays and return `True` if it does else you return `False`, you don't need the arrays it gets divided to, just the fact that it can be divided.

Well if it your array can be divided into 2 equal arrays, some of its elements should sum to the half of the total sum of your array.

For example :

```
[5,3,5,2,10,1]
```

This array has the sum of 26. if some of its elements can be equal to 13 then it can be divided into 2 arrays of equal arrays, because the rest of the elements would sum to 13 too. `example : [10,3] and [5,5,2,1]`, so you return True when you find that a combination of elements of your array equals half the sum of the total array. Also automatically an array with an odd sum is not dividable to 2 equal arrays. nb : searching for all combinations has a high complexity and will be slow with big lists.

This is what exactly i am doing, using itertools to get the combinations that sum to the half the total sum of the array, if there are combinations then it can be divided to 2 equal arrays, test it :

```
import itertools
numbers = [135, 129, 141, 121, 105, 109, 105, 147]


if((sum(numbers)%2)!=0):
    print(False)
else:
    result = [seq for i in range(len(numbers), 0, -1) for seq in itertools.combinations(numbers, i) if sum(seq) == (sum(numbers)//2)]
    if len(result)>1:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! however, sadly i am not allow to import any libraries for this question... thus i’m pretty stucked on how to do it w/o importing ang library

Comment: I added a second answer using no libraries, just a recursive function to check all combinations and return true once it finds one that when summing its numbers it equals sum of all numbers of array/2, it is faster and better and works flawlessly, check it out.

Comment: thank you, i have tried it but i'm trying to alter the code where it doesn't run in a nested function ~ however, the code that I've altered doesn't allow me to break out of the loop when i found the answer. I am also trying to return the array if true

Comment: Hi Elyes, I have updated my key answers + Post, is it possible for you to take a quick look and see if there's any solution, as currently i'm facing some issue. I'll note that issue in my main qns

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function that you need, it returns True when the array can be divided into 2 equal arrays and False if it cannot, without use of any libraries :

```
def search(numbers):
    target = sum(numbers)/2
    def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
        s = sum(partial)

        if s == target:
            print(5/0)
        if s >= target:
            return 

        for i in range(len(numbers)):
            n = numbers[i]
            remaining = numbers[i + 1:]
            subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])
    try:
        subset_sum(numbers, target)
        return False

    except:
        return True

numbers = [135, 129, 141, 121, 105, 109, 105, 147]
print(search(numbers))
```